# @HackerRank: FlippingBits. Wrong output

Tags: java

This one is really giving me a lot of hard time. So ultimately I decided to get some help from you guys. Perhaps, you can review it and tell me where I'm going wrong.

@ https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits

Basically:

> Input = Number
>
> 1. Convert it to binary String.
> 2. Flip the bits (Set all 0's and reset all 1's)
> 3. Output the Number you get by doing it.
>
> I have hard-coded a number for now, as it was mentioned in the
>   question (= 2147483647)

Problem is: It is giving me an output of:

```
0
```

Code:

```
public class FlippingBits {

private static String flipBits(String binaryOrig){
    String flippedString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<binaryOrig.length(); i++){
        if(binaryOrig.charAt(i) == '1')
            flippedString += '0';
        else 
            flippedString += '1';
    }
    return flippedString;
}

private static long getNum(String flippedString){
    long new_number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < flippedString.length(); i++){
        new_number = (2*new_number) + (flippedString.charAt(i) - '0');
    }
    return new_number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long num = 2147483647;
    String numBinaryString = Long.toBinaryString(num);
    String flippedString = flipBits(numBinaryString);
    System.out.println(Long.toString(getNum(flippedString)));
    }
};
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong! This is after trying for 3-4 hours. Sorry if it's trivial.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: An excerpt from the Question:

"Take 1 for example, as unsigned 32-bits is

00000000000000000000000000000001

and doing the flipping we get

11111111111111111111111111111110

which in turn is 4294967294"

So, I'm having a feeling it has to do something with long being 64-bits. !?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Java doesn't have unsigned types, and interprets integers in two's complement form, You'll need to address both.

For the first point, we can use a `long` to store the value. For the second point, we can bitmask with `0x00000000ffffffff` and get the 32-bit part we want.

```
int original = 1;
long flipped = ~original & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
System.out.println(flipped); 

// outputs 4294967294
```

Java has tools to handle tasks like this as seen above - I wouldn't break out into `String` manipulation unless I had to.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are converting the number to a string:

```
Long.toBinaryString(num)
```

Will not prefix the number with 0s, so for instance `3` will be `11` instead of `00000000000000000000000000000011`. Because of this your flipping method won't work the way the guys from hackerrank want it to work.

Notice that the question states the integers are 32-bit long (somewhere and not very clearly but oh well) so you need to take that into account.

@Edit: the easiest way to go around padding this would be:

```
numBinaryString = String.format("%32s",numBinaryString).replace(" ", "0")
```

Comment: I have noticed that, any idea what is the way around this?

Comment: you can either add the missing 0s yourself or use a different method to convert the number to binary string.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code. If you try to convert the long number 2147483647 to a binary number you will get 1111111111111111111111111111111.

And when you flip it, you get zero which is correct.

Apart from this, instead of manually creating decimal from binary number using `getNum`, you could use:

```
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(flippedString, 2));
```

I would suggest first you try with smaller number like 10 and see how you get 5 out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have got some answers already but let me give you an alternative way.

Use a long to store the value and then you can XOR it with 0xffffffffL (11111111111111111111111111111111 in binary). That will give you the correct answer.

For example:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111111 ^
--------------------------------
11111111111111111111111111111110
```

Below you can find the code. Note that I use custom IO methods.

```
long n = in.readLong() ^ 0xffffffffL;
out.print(n + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long flippingBits(long n)
{
    var binary = Convert.ToString(n,2).PadLeft(32,'0');
    var reverse = "";
    foreach(var item in binary){
        if(item == '1'){
            reverse = reverse + '0';
        }
        else{
            reverse = reverse + '1';
        }
    }
    
    return Convert.ToInt64(reverse,2);
}
```